# Combine CONCAT and DISTINCT mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

Given the table Test:

```
| id | name   | last_name |
---------------------------
| 1  | hello  | world     |
| 2  | hello  | world1    |
| 1  | foo    | bar       |
```

How can I select the **distinct** values from the name column and concatenate it with an prefix?

The preferred output would be:

```
| prefix_hello |
| prefix_foo   |
```

I tried the following query, which doesn't work:

```
Select CONCAT("prefix_", DISTINCT(a.name)) from Test a
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_, and can't be used like that.

Comment: @jarlh I did not know, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to update your query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT('prefix_', name) nameFROM `test`
```

**Note**
When only one expression is provided in the DISTINCT clause, the query will return the unique values for that expression.
When more than one expression is provided in the DISTINCT clause, the query will retrieve unique combinations for the expressions listed.
In MySQL, the DISTINCT clause doesn't ignore NULL values. So when using the DISTINCT clause in your SQL statement, your result set will include NULL as a distinct value.

OR

you can use group by

```
select CONCAT("prefix_", name) 
from Test 
group by name
```

for more information
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: I'd rather express it as "to return only distinct (different) _rows_." (In this case it's just one column.)

Answer (score 1):

use group by :

```
select CONCAT("prefix_", a.name) 
from Test a
group by a.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select DISTINCT CONCAT("prefix_", a.name) from Test a
```

It's a common misunderstanding that DISTINCT is a function. It's not — it's a query modifier. It must follow SELECT. Then after DISTINCT, you can use any conventional select-list of expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. unfortunately I can only pick one accepted answer, yours works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table Test( id int, name   varchar(50), last_name varchar(50));
 insert into Test values(1  , 'hello'  , 'world');
 insert into Test values(2  , 'hello'  , 'world1');
 insert into Test values(1  , 'foo'    , 'bar'   );
```

Query#1 To get distinct names with prefix in a single rows as comma separated string:

```
 select group_concat( distinct concat('prefix_',name)) Names
  from Test a
```

Output:

| Names |
| --- |
| prefix_hello,prefix_foo |

Query#2 To have Distinct names in with prefix separate rows in a column.

```
 Select DISTINCT CONCAT("prefix_", a.name)Names from Test a
```

Output:

| Names |
| --- |
| prefix_hello |
| prefix_foo |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=d9379efe35bb6f8fdaa761e29c272f8a)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation. unfortunately I can only pick one accepted answer, yours works as well.

Comment: Don't worry. You pick a good one. Thanks a lot for your polite response. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT("prefix_", T1.name) from (select distinct(a.name) as name from test)T1;
```

Comment: Can you provide explanation to your code in order to help your answer?